# ExecutorService causes JDBC connection Issue

Tags: java, jdbc

Many JDBC calls (querying DB and get results) are executed through ExecutorService. I found that when those calls are executed, JDBC connections gets a long time to get closed the connection even though those connections are closed correctly. Why I say so is, when a load test is run through JMeter, the database shows that many connections are in `IDLE in transaction`. If the number of thread which run the test is high, the number of connections in Idle in transactions goes up. If the test is run slowly, then connections get closed slowly (1, 2 minutes), that means there are connections in IDLE in transactions, but after few minutes they become IDLE. I use connection pool here too. If I run the JDBC querying functions as a sequence ( one after another), then database doesn't show any connections in IDLE in transactions.  Below is how I run my runnable tasks which run JDBC queries. TaskManager class handles whole ExecutorService related functions.

```
public class TaskManager {
    final private ThreadServiceFactory threadFactory;

    private int concurrentThreadCount;
    private  ExecutorService executerSV;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    // I keep a count of proposed tas task as servicecount
    public TaskManager(int serviceCount) {

        threadFactory = new ThreadServiceFactory();
        this.concurrentThreadCount = serviceCount;
        latch = new CountDownLatch(serviceCount);
    }

    public void execute( ThreadService runnableTask) {
        Object rv = null;

        runnableTask.setCountDownLatch(latch);

        if(executerSV == null) {
            executerSV = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.concurrentThreadCount, getThreadFactory());
        }

        executerSV.execute(runnableTask);
    }

    public boolean holdUntilComplete(){

        try {

            latch.await();
             executerSV.shutdown();
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;           
        }

    }

    private ThreadServiceFactory getThreadFactory(){
            threadFactory.setDeamon( Boolean.FALSE);
        return threadFactory;

    }

}
```

In my test class ;

```
 public void test(){
            TaskManager tm = new TaskManager(3);

            tm.execute(queryTask1);
            tm.execute(queryTask2);
            tm.holdUntilComplete();

}
```

queryTask1 is a Runnable and it calls JDBC select query.

If I run, `queryTask1.run(); queryTask2.run();`  then there are no any IDLE in connections in DB.

I use java 7. Please any one can let me know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no code in your question that opens any connection to a database. As such, it is difficult to suggest an answer. However, since you state that you are using a connection pool, you should better look at the pool configuration parameters, since they dictate how long an idle connection may be open before being elegible for eviction. For instance, if you are running a connection pool in tomcat, you should look particularly at "minIdle", "maxIdle" and "minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" properties. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer..  When I run  JDBC call one after another ( without ExecutorService) , there is no such "IDLE in transaction" connections in DB. Doesn't that mean, there is no issue in JDBC calls or pool configurations ? I tried my code many ways, and one last change was changing the way of these tasks running which is using Executor and without, where I found, IDLE in transaction are not appeared when running as  a sequence.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think I can be of much help without having further details of what you are doing (queries you are running, DBMS you are using) but it looks like you have a concurrency issue with the queries. This post (http://serverfault.com/questions/660642/what-could-cause-idle-in-transaction-in-a-pentaho-pdi-process) describes a similar issue and suggest that the problem may be in the code itself, such as a transaction being started and never finished. Observe that this kind of problem may not appear if you run the transactions sequentially, as it seems to be your case.